# How do I run ng e2e against a remote server?

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I want to run the the angular cli's `ng e2e` tests against a web application that is being served by someone else (other than angular cli).  How do I specify the host and port of the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.  It's specified in the `protractor.conf.js` file at the root of the angular project:

```
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify in your config, and then override on the cli...

```
protractor conf.js --baseUrl https://adomain.com
```